# For each with my custom class won't work

Tags: java

Hey everybody I'm working with Java.
So I am writing a class called **OrderedSet**. It is a class that is cross between a set and a queue. In other words, it is a queue without any duplicates. So I know I have to implement the *Iterable* interface, and write an iterator method. To write the method I have to then implement the *Iterator* interface.

```
package comp345;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

class OrderedSet implements Iterable<Object> {
    private Object[] queue; // This is how the OrderedSet is represented, a
                            // queue of Objects
    private int counter; // Counter to keep track of current position of queue
    private int queueSize; // Keep track of the queue;

    // Constructor
    public OrderedSet(int size) {
        this.queue = new Object[size];
        this.counter = 0;
        this.queueSize = size - 1;

        // Instantiate each instance of the object in the object array
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
            queue[i] = new Object();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ensures that this collection contains the specified element. If it is not
     * already in the collection it is added it to the back of the queue.
     * 
     * @param e
     *            element whose presence in this collection is to be ensured
     * @return true if this collection changed as a result of the call
     * @throws NullPointerException
     *             if the specified element is null
     */
    boolean add(Object i) {
        if (i == queue[counter]) {
            return false;
        } else if (i == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        else {
            // Add Object to back of Queue
            queue[counter] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes all of the elements from this collection. The collection will be
     * empty after this method returns.
     */
    void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
            queue[i] = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this collection contains no elements.
     * 
     * @return true if this collection contains no elements
     */
    boolean isEmpty() {
        if (queue[0] == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns null
     * if this queue is empty
     * 
     * @return the head of this queue, or null if this queue is empty
     */
    Object peek() {
        if (queue[counter] != null)
            return queue[counter];
        else
            return null;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves and removes the head of the queue.
     * 
     * @return the head of this queue
     * @throws NoSuchElementException
     *             if this queue is empty
     */
    Object remove() {
        if (queue[0] != null) {
            Object temp = queue[0];

            queue[0] = queue[1];

            return temp;

        } else
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    public class SetIterator implements Iterator<Object> {
        private int counter;

        public SetIterator() {
            this.counter = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            counter++;

            if (queueSize == counter)
                return null;

            else if (queue[counter] != null)
                return (Object) queue[counter];

            else
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            counter++;

            if (queueSize < counter)
                return false;
            else if (queue[counter] != null)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new SetIterator();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OrderedSet os;
        os.add("hello");
        os.add(4);
        os.add("bye");

        for (Object o : os) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So...what exactly is your question?

Comment: Please show the "foreach" code that doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I edited the program by adding main which shows where its not working.

Comment: So why don't you use `TreeSet`?  I guess this is homework?

Comment: Yes it is, the teacher wants us to implement our own for each.

Comment: What are you expecting the code to print out?

Comment: I expect the code to print out the values that I added to my object

Comment: Is the program you are compiling and running is same as the one listed above? I don't see something like 
OrderedSet os = new OrderedSet(size) in your main method at all.

Comment: Yes it is, I forgot to instantiate it, sorry i meant to do that.

Comment: Your add() method isn't going to work anyway. It doesn't look through the collection to see if the item is already present, it uses == instead of equals and it doesn't update the size of the collection when/if it adds the item. It uses the counter object variable but that could have an invalid value (greater than size of collection) if the iterator has been used previously

Answer (score 4):

I can see at least one problem.
Take a closer look at your `hasNext()` method.

Do you really want to increment the variable `counter`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is here:

```
 OrderedSet os;       
 os.add("hello");
```

You have declared a reference of os, but you haven't assigned it anything. The compiler won't allow this. You have to do:

```
 OrderedSet os = new OrderedSet(10);
```

There are other problems with your code (@hallidave found one) but that is the first problem.

In general when you have a problem with an error, you should ask with more information than "it doesn't work." The exact error message will go a long way to answering the question. I know compiler error messages don't mean much to you yet, but when you get more experience they will.